# Segmentation fault in linked list program (c language)

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to write a code for linked lists using c++. Insert at begin and Insert at end are not working for some reason. Here is the code.

`

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>
void insertAtBeginning(int );
void insertAtEnd(int );
void printLL();

struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node *link;
};
struct Node *head;


int main()
{
    struct Node *temp, *newnode;
    int ch=1, i=1, info;
    head = NULL;
    while(ch)
    {
        printf("Enter data: ");
        scanf("%d", &info);
        
        newnode = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
        
        newnode->data = info;
        newnode->link = NULL;
        
        if(head == NULL)
        {
            head = newnode;
            temp = newnode;
        }
        else
        {
            temp ->link = newnode;
            temp = newnode;
        }
        printf("You wish to continue? (press 0 to terminate)\n");
        scanf("%d",&ch);
        if(!ch)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    temp = head;
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%d -> ",temp->data);
        temp = temp->link;
    }
    printf("\n");
    insertAtBeginning(50);
    insertAtEnd(150);
    //printLL();
    
}

void insertAtBeginning(int info)
{
    struct Node *newnode;
    newnode->data = info;
    printf("\n%d\n", newnode ->data);
    newnode->link = head;
    head = newnode;
}

void insertAtEnd(int info)
{
    struct Node *temp, *newnode;
    newnode->link = NULL;
    newnode->data = info;
    temp = head;
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        temp = temp->link;
    }
    temp->link = newnode;
    printf("\n%d\n", newnode -> data);
}

void printLL()
{
    struct Node *temp;
    temp = head;
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%d -> ",temp->data);
        temp = temp->link;
    }
}
```

`

The problem is somewhere around `newnode->data = info` in the functions.

I created two functions, one to insert an element at beginning and one to insert an element at end. In both of them, i've created a newnode. The problem is I cannot insert data into those nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to append a new node to the end of a linked list, you must find your last node (a node which its link is NULL, not itself). Also, it is better to use meaningful variable name (`temp` is too general name). You also forgot to `malloc` new nodes in `insertAtBeginning` and `insertAtEnd` functions. I've fixed these issues in the following code

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void insertAtBeginning(int );
void insertAtEnd(int );
void printLL();

struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node *link;
};

struct Node *head = NULL;


int main()
{
    struct Node *it, *newnode, *tail;
    int ch=1, i=1, info;

    while(ch){
        printf("Enter data: ");
        scanf("%d", &info);

        newnode = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
        newnode->data = info;
        newnode->link = NULL;

        if (head == NULL) {
            head = newnode;
            tail = newnode;
        } else {
            tail->link = newnode;
            tail = newnode;
        }

        printf("You wish to continue? (press 0 to terminate, else to continue)\n");
        scanf("%d",&ch);
        if(ch == 0) {
            break;
        }
    }

    it = head;
    while(it != NULL) {
        printf("%d -> ",it->data);
        it = it->link;
    }

    printf("\n");
    insertAtBeginning(50);
    insertAtEnd(150);
}

void insertAtBeginning(int info)
{
    struct Node *newnode;

    newnode = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    newnode->data = info;
    printf("\n%d\n", newnode->data);
    newnode->link = head;
    head = newnode;
}

void insertAtEnd(int info)
{
    struct Node *it, *newnode;

    newnode = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    newnode->link = NULL;
    newnode->data = info;
    it = head;
    while(it->link != NULL)
    {
        it = it->link;
    }
    it->link = newnode;
    printf("\n%d\n", newnode->data);
}

void printLL()
{
    struct Node *it;
    it = head;
    while(it!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%d -> ",it->data);
        it = it->link;
    }
}
```

Comment: It works, was foolish of me not to allocate memory. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You're treating your uninitialized stack variable (`struct Node *newnode`) as a pointer to a `struct Node` and trying to update its fields:

```
struct Node *newnode;
newnode->data = info;
```

This doesn't work because the value of `newnode` is whatever garbage was on the stack beforehand, and trying to deref it (`*newnode`) will likely give a seg fault since you're trying to read from some unknown memory address.

Notice how inside `main`, you assign a result from `malloc` to `newnode`, this means you know that (given that `malloc` didn't return `NULL`), the pointer is valid, and you're free to use the memory it points to.